# Method returns proper value but if loop does not act accordingly

Tags: java, methods

I've written out all the code for an assignment for my programming class. The assignment requires us to create a program that allows the user to play rock paper scissors against a computer. We're required to have individual methods to obtain the computer's choice, the user's choice, check if the user's choice is valid, and also to determine the winner of the match. If a match doesn't end in a tie we need to print why the match was won, eg. "Scissors cuts Paper," and print who wins. Everything works properly, except when the user wins it's never counted or announced. For example instead of printing:

The computer's choice was rock. The user's choice was paper. Paper covers Rock. The user wins!

it prints:

The computer's choice was rock. The user's choice was paper. Paper covers Rock.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class FinalRockPaperScissors {

//Computer's Choice
public static int computersChoice (int options) {
    Random randGen = new Random();
    int computerValue = randGen.nextInt(options)+1;
    System.out.println(computerValue); //FOR TESTING ONLY
    return computerValue;
}

//Player's Choice
public static int usersChoice () {
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter 1 for rock, 2 for paper, or 3 for scissors: ");
    int userValue = scnr.nextInt();

    if (isValid(userValue) == true) {
        return userValue;
    }

    else {
        userValue = 0;
        return userValue;
    }


}

//Check for valid user input
public static boolean isValid (int userInput){
    if (userInput == 1 || userInput == 2 || userInput == 3) {
        return true;
    }

    else {
        return false;
    }
}

//Checking winner
public static char determineWinner () {
    char win;
    int computerValue = computersChoice(3);
    int userValue = usersChoice();

    //print computer choices
    if (computerValue == 1) {
        System.out.println("The computer's choice was rock.");
    }

    else if (computerValue == 2) {
        System.out.println("The computer's choice was paper.");
    }

    else if (computerValue == 3){
        System.out.println("The computer's choice was scissors.");
    }

    //print user choices
            if (userValue == 1) {
                System.out.println("The user's choice was rock.");
            }

            else if (userValue == 2) {
                System.out.println("The user's choice was paper.");
            }

            else if (userValue == 3){
                System.out.println("The user's choice was scissors.");
            }


    //check who won
    if (computerValue == 1) { //rock vs
        if (userValue == 2) {           //paper
            System.out.println("Paper wraps Rock.");
            return win = 'b'; 
        }

        else if (userValue == 3) {      //scissors
            System.out.println("Rock smashes Scissors.");
            return win = 'a'; 
        }

        else if (userValue == 1){                           //rock
            return win = 'c'; 
        }

        else {
            System.out.println("The user chose an invalid number. This round will be ignored.");
            return win = 'd';
        }

    }

    else if (computerValue == 2) { //paper vs
        if (userValue == 2) {           //paper
            return win = 'c'; 
        }

        else if (userValue == 3) {      //scissors
            System.out.println("Scissors cuts Paper.");
            return win = 'b'; 
        }

        else if (userValue == 1){                           //rock
            System.out.println("Paper wraps Rock.");
            return win = 'a'; 
        }

        else {
            System.out.println("The user chose an invalid number. This round will be ignored.");
            return win = 'd';
        }

    }

    else { //scissors vs
        if (userValue == 2) { //paper
            System.out.println("Scissors cuts Paper.");
            return win = 'a';
        }

        else if (userValue == 3) { //scissors
            return win = 'c';
        }

        else if (userValue == 1){ //rock
            System.out.println("Rock smashes Scissors.");
            return win = 'b';
        }

        else {
            System.out.println("The user chose an invalid number. This round will be ignored.");
            return win = 'd';
        }

    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int userWins = 0;
    int computerWins = 0;
    int ties = 0;
    int error = 0;

    //for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) { //5 for testing purposes
        if (determineWinner() == 'a') {
            System.out.println("The computer wins!");
            System.out.println("");
            computerWins++;
        }

        else if (determineWinner() == 'b') {
            System.out.println("The user wins!");
            System.out.println("");
            userWins++;
        }

        else if (determineWinner() == 'c'){
            System.out.println("The game is tied!");
            System.out.println("");
            ties++;
        }

        else {
            error++;
        }
    //}

    System.out.println("The number of ties is " + ties);
    System.out.println("The number of user wins is " + userWins);
    System.out.println("The number of computer wins is " + computerWins);

    //output final winner
    if (computerWins > userWins) {
        System.out.println("Computer is the winner.");
    }

    else if (userWins > computerWins) {
        System.out.println("User is the winner.");
    }

    else {
        if (userWins == computerWins) {
            System.out.println("User is the winner.");
        }
        else if (computerWins == ties) {
            System.out.println("Computer is the winner.");
        }
    }


}

}
```

After some testing I've discovered that the problem may be with my `userchoice()` method. If I disable this method and give a set value for the user, everything works as it should. The problem is I don't know why it doesn't work, and as a result I can't fix it.

Comment: the method name `determineWinner` is not very accurate, actually the method is more like `playOneRound` - than see user9849588's answer (or use one switch instead of if's)

Comment: Why do you need a for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're so new to `Java` and also let's start to show you your mistake in this code, you called `determineWinner()` multiple times which shouldn't be like that because you repeat the game four times to determine the result once, so you should call it once and get the returned value and check the value, like:-

```
char result = determineWinner(); //Play the game and get the result

// use it in conditions

if (result == 'a') {  
    System.out.println("The computer wins!");
    System.out.println("");
    computerWins++;
}

else if (result == 'b') {
    System.out.println("The user wins!");
    System.out.println("");
    userWins++;
}

else if (result == 'c'){
    System.out.println("The game is tied!");
    System.out.println("");
    ties++;
}

else {
    error++;
}
```

Comment: Ah okay, I see what I did wrong. Thank you! This fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

In your `main` function You are calling `determineWinner()` every time you test your if condition. The proper way would be to store the returned value in a variable and then check if that variable is 'a', 'b' or 'c'. For example:

```
char result = determineWinner();
if (result == 'a') {
    System.out.println("The computer wins!");
    System.out.println("");
    computerWins++;
}
```